# Using Jena in OSGi - NoClassDefFoundException on javax/management/MalformedObjectNameException

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, jena

I am about to convert an existing OSGi project that uses Jena 2.6.4 to another framework (from Eclipse Equinox to Apache Felix in combination with BndTools). The old project on Equinox worked very well, however, I have some trouble with the new framework.
In order to include the Jena libraries into my project, I created a new "Plugin from existing JAR Archives". I exported that to a deployable Plugin and put that into my local repository. From there I could add it to my project's build path. It seemed to work well. It could be compiled, but when I started the project, on the first access to Jena (createResource) a NoClassDefFoundException on org.xml.sax.SAXException.
To solve this problem, I decided to upgrade the Jena libraries to 2.7 (from [a here](http://www.apache.org/dist/incubator/jena/)). So I did the exact same steps as above. The project, again, could compile and ran a little further. Now, the createResource-call did not crash and worked very well. However, the project crashed while performing a SPARQL-Query. Here's an excerpt of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/MalformedObjectNameException
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.init(ARQ.java:437)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.<clinit>(ARQ.java:456)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query.<clinit>(Query.java:62)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:80)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:52)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.makeQuery(QueryExecutionFactory.java:517)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.create(QueryExecutionFactory.java:193)
```

And, indeed, I was not able to find the definition of this exception in the Jena libraries. Have I missed anything? Or any other ideas, how to solve this?

Nico

Comment: I could solve the problem by modifying the OSGi wrapper project for Jena. When the javax.management package is added as a dependency, then everything works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I need these JARs:

- jena-arq-2.9.0-incubating.jar
- jena-core-2.7.0-incubating.jar
- jena-iri-0.9.0-incubating.jar
- xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
- icu4j-3.4.4.jar

When I first encountered this problem with Jena, I missed the `icu4j` one.

I'll post the stacktrace here in case someone Googles :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.BuiltinPersonalities
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<init>(ModelCom.java:62)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:142)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:136)
        at com.satukancinta.dump.command.SiteExport$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SiteExport.scala:198)
        at com.satukancinta.dump.command.SiteExport$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SiteExport.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bundle providing Jena TDB in the apache clerezza project. It has maven groupId org.apache.clerezza.ext and artifactId org.apache.jena.tdb. Not much documentation unfortunately. The source are here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/clerezza/trunk/ext.org.apache.jena.tdb/.